# Canonical tags for separate mobile URLs

Tags: canonical-url, mobile

I have a Drupal website serving mobile pages from different urls (starting from /mobile). According to [Google recommendations](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details#separateurls) I should use the canonical tag to map desktop and mobile pages.

Right now I did this in case I serve the same node (e.g: node/123 and mobile/node/123) but should I do this for other pages as well that are equivalent but share a different content?
For example do I need to map the desktop and mobile homepages even if they don't have the same content at all?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to separate the desktop and mobile versions completely. It means, you should place canonical from every page of your mobile version to every page of your desktop version.

Comment: But if you have different content on the mobile version of the page, would the canonical tag actually work? As the canonicalised page should have the same content as the page its being canonicaled too. This is an interesting question which isn't answered specifically in Google's guidldines.

Comment: If the primary content isn't equivalent, don't use the rel=canonical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
but should I do this for other pages as well that are equivalent but share
a different content? For example do I need to map the desktop and mobile
homepages even if they don't have the same content at all?
```

Simple answer: no. Why: because they have different content. Canonical is for pages with different URLs and same (or nearly same) content only.